# UISearchBarController iOS 11 issue - SearchBar and scope buttons overlap

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

Referred [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46192417/swift-4-tableview-and-scopebuttons-slide-under-searchbar-in-ios-11) and [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424540/uisearchcontroller-searchbar-and-scopebar-overlap-on-first-touch-event). No answer in first link. In the second link, though the answer is not accepted, but the link to apple developer forum gives error.

Before iOS 11 :

[image]

iOS 11 :

[image]

**Note** : Same device same code.
Also, this would mean, all apps using this feature have to be republished ?

Comment: see this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424540/uisearchcontroller-searchbar-and-scopebar-overlap-on-first-touch-event

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik This link is attached by Nitish

Comment: Try with self.definesPresentationContext = true
write this line in your viewDIdload

Comment: @TofaaniKaanudo : Already there

Comment: is your searchbar in your navigation bar ? or there is  no navigation bar in that viewcontroller ?

Comment: @Lion : There is a navigation bar but the searcher is not in it. It is tableview's header.

Comment: I encounter the same issue. Worked fine on iOS 10. To mee it seams UISearchController is just completely broken in iOS 11.0.

Comment: The example on this site displays the same issue: https://www.raywenderlich.com/157864/uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started. Searching on Twitter reveals more victims of this bug, Apple really dropped the ball on this one.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43278771/5329717 ?

Comment: have you tried this `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true;` for iOS 11?

Answer (score 7):

Adding these lines fixed it for me:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    self.searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
}
```

Comment: Fixed for me too. I just added SearchController to the tableView without conditionally checking for iOS 11. It has to be linked against iOS 11 SDK though, this method is not working when linked against iOS 10 SDK.

Comment: For iOS 11, the top ranked answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45782669/swift-4-ios-11-search-bar-scope-wont-appear-as-it-should/46351518#46351518 is the way.

Answer (score 2):

I can get the initial appearance to display correctly in iOS11 using the following code (as per greg's answer):

```
[self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];

if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    self.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchController;
    self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = NO;
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
}
```

However, if the app is backgrounded then restored while the search bar was active, the appearance would end up overlapped as shown in Nitish's second screenshot above.

I was able to fix that with the following workaround:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification * _Nonnull note) {
    self.searchController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = NO;
    [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
    self.searchController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;
    [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
}];
```

(I'm still working on how to workaround the layout issues following an interface orientation change while the search bar is active - that still ends up overlapped.)

Answer (score 1):

In the radar that Ray Wenderlich filed, @benck posted this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46351518/543296) from WWDC, which, if I'm not mistaken, hasn't been posted yet.

Answer (score 1):

Per your comments, your `UISearchController`'s `UISearchBar` has been assigned to your `UITableView`'s `tableHeaderView`. In iOS 11, you should instead be assigning your `UISearchController` to the `searchController` property of your view's `navigationItem`. You no longer need to assign the `UISearchBar` anywhere. See [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/2897305-searchcontroller) on this new property.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same issue on my app, my solution is in iOS 11, using apple suggested new way for searchBar which is in navigationItem, otherwise, using the old way. My code in viewDidLoad() as below:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    searchViewHeight.constant = 0
} else {
    searchView.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
}
```

I have two IBOutlets: searchView and searchViewHeight:

```
@IBOutlet var searchView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var searchViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint! // new added for iOS 11
```

Before iOS 11, my viewController's hierarchy as below:

[image: My searchView before iOS 11]

I have a searchView which height is 44 to contains my searchController's searchBar view. It's under navigation bar.

In iOS 11, I add a new IBOutlet for searchView's height constraint, and set its constant to 0, hide this container view. And add searchController as a part of navigation item.

See apple's document:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/2897305-searchcontroller

One more thing is under iOS 11, the searchBar's textField background color is little darker than navigation bar color by default. For consistency, you can change it to white, the below code will work both for iOS11 and its prior:

```
if let textField = searchController.searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {
    if let backgroundView = textField.subviews.first {

        // Search bar textField background color
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        // Search bar textField rounded corner
        backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        backgroundView.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the solution is to add the Search Bar in the Navigation Bar:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true // Navigation bar large titles
navigationItem.title = "Contacts"
navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 0/255, green: 150/255, blue: 136/255, alpha: 1.0)

let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil) // Search Controller
navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

You can find an example for UISearchBarController - SearchBar and scope buttons overlap [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/157864/uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started).

Answer (score 0):

**I had the same issue in iOS 11.**

Contrary to some of the comments here, if I look at your screenshots you DONT want to set it as the `navigationItem` because you don't have a `UINavigationController` setup.

Neither do you want to add the `searchBar` in the header of the `tableView` because for some reason it can't cope with the `scopeBar`

**So what I did to fix it:**

To get a `UISearchBar` with scopes over your `tableView`, use a `UIViewController` in interface builder **not** a `UITableViewController`.

Place a `UISearchBar` and a `UITableView` inside the view controller and wire them up properly (delegates, dataSource, etc).

Don't forget to change your swift file to `UIViewController` instead of `UITableViewController` as well and change it accordingly. (add a tableView property and connect it via `IBOutlet`, change the delegates for the tableView etc)

Then in interface builder, use autoLayout guides so the `searchBar` sits on top of the `tableView`

[image]

In interface builder when you activate the scope bar it will look totally weird but don't panic, it will be fine. I guess Apple screwed the rendering n interface builder when they changed the behavior to work with `UINavigationController`... anyway...

Then everything works as it should and look like this (in my case I present it the vc in a popover but that doesn't matter)

[image]