# UITableView calling cellFor row but doesn't draw in UI

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am calling an API to search for "friends" / (UserProfile class) and want to display it in a tableView. I also search for places in a local Session which works fine.

But after switching to the friends segmented control (see below) entering a user name and pressing return the tableView in the Friends Mode stays empty. But the logs indicate it was found and the cellForRowAt: returns something. The friend does only show up in my tableView when I enter one letter of the query the second time (no query to the API because I don't press enter).

Thought its probably the async stuff but seems fine, attached a log.

```
//
//  FilterViewController.swift


import Foundation
import UIKit

class FilterViewController: UIViewController {
  enum SearchState: String {
    case place = "Search for a place"
    case friend = "Search for a friend"
  }
  var searchState: SearchState = .place
  var placesResult: Array<Place> = []
  var friendResult: Array<UserProfile> = []
  @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.placesResult = Session.shared.places
    self.searchBar.isTranslucent = true
    self.searchBar.autocapitalizationType = .none
    // self.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .prominent
    self.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.clear
    self.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = [SearchState.place.rawValue, SearchState.friend.rawValue]
  }

  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.searchBar.showsScopeBar = true
    self.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    self.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
  }
}

extension FilterViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {

  // The places part works fine
  func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchText == "" {
      self.friendResult = []
      self.placesResult = []
      return
    }
    guard self.searchState == .place else {
      return
    }
    self.placesResult = Session.places(matching: searchText)
    print("FilterView search query: \(searchText)")
    tableView.reloadData()
  }

  func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    /// We use it only for friends because for places we search on text change
    guard self.searchState == .friend else {
      return
    }
    //// HERE IS THE PART WHERE I QUERY.
    let query = UserProfileQuery(forName: searchBar.text!)
    query.performQuery() { results, error in
      print("Search User results: \(results.count) users")
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.friendResult.removeAll()
        print("reload")
        for result in results {
          print(">>> Results: \(result["name"].debugDescription)")
          let userProfile = UserProfile(fromRecord: result)
          self.friendResult.append(userProfile)
        }
        print("calling tableView reloadSections. \(self.friendResult.count) friends")
        // self.tableView.reloadSections([0], with: .left)
        //self.tableView.reloadSections([0], with: .left)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        //// AFTER THIS THE TABLEVIEW CALLS THE DATA SOURCE. ALL GOOD SO FAR
      }
    }

  }



  func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.text = ""
  }

  func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

  func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
    switch selectedScope {
    case 0:
      self.searchState = .place
      self.searchBar.placeholder = SearchState.place.rawValue
    case 1:
      self.searchState = .friend
      self.searchBar.placeholder = SearchState.friend.rawValue
    default:
      print("Error: searchbar in FilterViewController has unknown scope: \(selectedScope)")
    }
  }

}


extension FilterViewController: UITableViewDelegate {


  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("willDisplay cell: \(cell.debugDescription)")
  }

}

extension FilterViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

  func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch self.searchState {
    case .place:
      print("Place \(self.placesResult.count)")
      return self.placesResult.count
    case .friend:
      print("numberOfRowsInSection: \(self.friendResult.count) friends")
      return self.friendResult.count
    }
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print("cellForRowAt: for state \(self.searchState) \(self.friendResult.count)")
    switch self.searchState {
    case .place:
      let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "placeCell")!
      cell.textLabel?.text = self.placesResult[indexPath.item].name
      print("return place cell")
      return cell
    case .friend:
      let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "friendCell")!
      cell.textLabel?.text = self.friendResult[indexPath.item].name
      //cell.userProfile = self.friendResult[indexPath.item]
      //cell.title.text = cell.userProfile.name
      print("return cell: \(cell.debugDescription)")
      return cell
    }

  }
}
```

And here is the log from the prints above:

```
numberOfRowsInSection: 0 friends
numberOfRowsInSection: 0 friends
numberOfRowsInSection: 0 friends
numberOfRowsInSection: 0 friends
numberOfRowsInSection: 0 friends
Search User results: 1 users
reload
>>> Results: Optional(johnappleseed)
calling tableView reloadSections. 1 friends
numberOfRowsInSection: 1 friends
cellForRowAt: for state friend 1
return cell: <UITableViewCell: 0x7fdd15f02400; frame = (0 0; 300 44); text = 'johnappleseed'; clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x604001e25160>>
willDisplay cell: <UITableViewCell: 0x7fdd15f02400; frame = (0 0; 300 44); text = 'johnappleseed'; clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W; tintColor = UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0 0 1 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x604001e25160>>
numberOfRowsInSection: 1 friends
cellForRowAt: for state friend 1
return cell: <UITableViewCell: 0x7fdd16651a00; frame = (0 0; 300 44); text = 'johnappleseed'; clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000182b4e0>>
willDisplay cell: <UITableViewCell: 0x7fdd16651a00; frame = (0 0; 300 44); text = 'johnappleseed'; clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W; tintColor = UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0 0 1 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000182b4e0>>
numberOfRowsInSection: 1 friends
cellForRowAt: for state friend 1
return cell: <UITableViewCell: 0x7fdd15802000; frame = (0 0; 300 44); text = 'johnappleseed'; clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x604001e2eec0>>
willDisplay cell: <UITableViewCell: 0x7fdd15802000; frame = (0 0; 300 44); text = 'johnappleseed'; clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W; tintColor = UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0 0 1 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x604001e2eec0>>
```

So it should definitely show the cell but is shows this:

[image]

Then when I click in the searchBar again and enter "J" it shows the cell:

[image]

What is wrong here?

Comment: Did you try reloading the `tableView` on the `main` thread? ```DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}```

Comment: Yes you can see that in the sample code. After the query (which is async) I call DispatchQueue and reload in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found it.

So I guess some of it has to to with the changes Apple did for iOS 11 to support `searchBar` to be used in `UINavigationController`.

What I did wrong is I assigned the `searchBar` to be the `tableViewHeader`.

That breaks when the `searchBar` shows a `scopeBar`.

In that case it works if the `searchBar` is a separate thing from the tableView and connected with auto layout so `searchBar` sits on top of the `tableView`.

In that case a `UIViewController` is the container not a `UITableViewController`

I posted more details in this thread: [UISearchBarController iOS 11 issue - SearchBar and scope buttons overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46364224/uisearchbarcontroller-ios-11-issue-searchbar-and-scope-buttons-overlap/49345966#49345966)

So layout should look like this in IB:

[image]

Looks very weird in IB but it works totally as expected.
Guess its a bug in IB